# SML - Error: operator and operand do not agree [overload - bad instantiation]

Tags: compiler-errors, type-inference, sml

I'm very new to [SML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML) and I need help with this problem,

What I'm trying to do is, I have a list of tuples of int * int and the output is a list where the elements of the tuples are added up, like this:

```
[(1,2),(3,4)...] = [3,7,....]
```

This is the code I did for this, but I have an error that I don't know how to solve

```
fun sumpares [] = []
  | sumpares [(x,y)] = [x+y]
  | sumpares ((x,y)::xs) = [x+y]::sumpares(xs)
```

This is the error:

```
stdIn:68.28-68.47 Error: operator and operand do not agree [overload - bad instantiation]
  operator domain: 'Z[OL(+,+)] list * 'Z[OL(+,+)] list list
  operand:         'Z[OL(+,+)] list * 'Z[OL(+,+)] list
  in expression:
    (x + y :: nil) :: sumpares xs
```

How can I fix it? Also, is there a way to do this if you have lists instead of tuples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your `sumpares` function. If we give it an empty list, it returns an empty list. That's easy.

In the next case, we feed it an `(int * int) list` and we get an `int list` in return. So far the type of `sumpares` is `(int * int) list -> int list`. But now consider the next case.

`((x,y)::xs)` does match an `(int * int) list` *but* then you return: `[x+y]::sumpares(xs)`. An `int list` cannot be added to the front of an `int list` using `::`. This would only work if `sumpares(xs)` returned an `int list list`.

There are a few ways to fix this.

First, there is no need for the second case with a single tuple at all. Let's get rid of that.

```
fun sumpares [] = []
  | sumpares ((x,y)::xs) = [x+y]::sumpares(xs)
```

This actually will compile because `[]` is an `int list list`, but an `int list list` is not what you're looking for. To get the desired result...

We could use the `@` operator to concatenate the two lists.

```
fun sumpares [] = []
  | sumpares ((x,y)::xs) = [x+y] @ sumpares(xs)
```

But this is much less efficient than just constructing a list by tacking `x+y` onto the front of the list created by the recursive call.

```
fun sumpares [] = []
  | sumpares ((x,y)::xs) = (x+y) :: sumpares(xs)
```

It may also be useful to realize that what you're doing is reimplementing a very specific use of `map`.

```
val sumpares = map op+
```

You can definitely see this by looping at a simple implementation of `map`.

```
fun map _ [] = []
  | map f (x::xs) = f x :: map f xs
```